# Using modulo operator to get a sample

Tags: mysql, sql, sample, modulo

How can I use the Modulo operator to get a sample?

If I have a set of IDs that are just random numbers, and I want a 1% sample, I know I can do 'random_id % 101 = 0'. Does this mean 'random_id % 11 = 0' is a 10% sample?

Comment: Why is it `101` and not `100`? There are 101 possibilities for `N % 101` - from zero to 100, *inclusive*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not random if you are selecting every nth element.

Comment: The ID numbers have no significance, so you can assume they were randomly generated. Now I just need a one time 10% sample.

Comment: Even then, there will be bias if the number of IDs is not a multiple of 100, see [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5708/creating-a-small-number-from-a-cryptographically-secure-random-string) for an explanation and possible sampling schemes. Though perhaps the bias doesn't matter in this particular situation.

Comment: "so you can assume they were randomly generated."  Then just take the first bunch of numbers that are 1% of the total.